# [Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray _dataForIntentSlotDescription:]:

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, swift2

I have the following error message in log while execution Intent extension to Start Video Call with my app:

```
2016-09-28 23:56:58.686343 CallIntentExtension[2442:128209] -[Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray _dataForIntentSlotDescription:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x143d29a50  
2016-09-28 23:56:58.703162 CallIntentExtension[2442:128209] <NSXPCConnection: 0x143e3b2a0> connection from pid 25: Warning: Exception caught during invocation of received message, dropping incoming message and invalidating the connection.  
Exception: -[Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray _dataForIntentSlotDescription:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x143d29a50  
-[Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray _dataForIntentSlotDescription:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x143d29a50  
(  
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019471c1d8 <redacted> + 148  
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019315455c objc_exception_throw + 56  
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000194723278 <redacted> + 0  
  3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000194720278 <redacted> + 916  
  4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019461a59c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92  
  5   Intents                             0x00000001adde1dd0 <redacted> + 36  
  6   CallIntentExtension                 0x00000001000179fc _TTRXFdCb_dCSo7NSArray_dT__XFo_oGSaCSo24INPersonResolutionResult__dT__ + 72  
  7   CallIntentExtension                 0x000000010001748c _TFC19CallIntentExtension17CallIntentHandler15resolveContactsfT17  
resolveContacts
```

Application was updated to swift 2.3 before the start of extension developing.
The message to Siri is: *"Start the video call with AppName to ContactName".*
Resolve methods is called:

```
func resolveContacts(forStartVideoCall intent: INStartVideoCallIntent, with completion: ([INPersonResolutionResult]) -> Void)
```

Success resolution result is provided to completion block:

```
var resolutionResults = [INPersonResolutionResult]()   
let handle = INPersonHandle(value: "ContactName", type: .Unknown)   
let person = INPerson(personHandle: handle, nameComponents: nil, displayName: "ContactName", image: nil, contactIdentifier: "123", customIdentifier: nil)   
resolutionResults += [.success(with: person)]  
completion(resolutionResults)
```

But after the error message appears in log and Siri says: *"Sorry, you'll need to continue in the app".*
Perform or Handle methods aren't called.
The same is happend with new clear application. You can find the project [here](https://github.com/OlesyaS/SiriWithSwift2.3).

Please, help me to understand what is wrong? Any thoughts?

P.S.

I didn't find any information about `-[Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray _dataForIntentSlotDescription:]:`

P.P.S.

If convert the application to Swift 3, the error is gone.

Comment: Where do you create `resolutionResults` ? Is it definitely an array?

Comment: Yes. The code is: 
   
var resolutionResults = [INPersonResolutionResult]()
      let handle = INPersonHandle(value:  "ContactName", type: .Unknown)
      let person = INPerson(personHandle: handle, nameComponents: nil,
                      displayName: "ContactName", image: nil,
                      contactIdentifier: "123", customIdentifier: nil)
      resolutionResults += [.success(with: person)]

Comment: Edit your question and put the code there please

Comment: The question was edited.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out what was the problem? Having the same issue with Swift 2.3.

Comment: @clawoo, Unfortunately no. We've spent a time to convert our project to Swift 3. And it solved the problem. The question is still opened. There is a one on Dev forum without reply: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/183938#183938